# Can not register function for option in pjax

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, pjax

[Pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/blob/master/jquery.pjax.js) will not allow me to specify functions as an option when calling it directly.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a.inferno-preview', function(event) {
  return $.pjax.click(event, {
    container: '#preview-overlay',
    fragment: '#preview-overlay',
    send: function() {
      return $('#preview-overlay').removeClass('hidden');
    },
    complete: function() {}
  });
});
```

In this case, the 'send' and 'complete' functions are not being executed, while 'container' and 'fragment' is working well. Why is this and what do I need to do to make Pjax recognize my functions?

By the way: I can not use the [conventional form of using Pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax#overview), I need more control about the happening, so I need to use the `$.pjax.click` object. Yet it would work fine with the functions in the common way like in the following:

```js
$(document).pjax('a.inferno-preview', '#preview-overlay', {
    send: function() { alert('this will work.'); }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In pjax `send` and `complete` events are not called if a request if retrieved from cache so you will not get your overlay down. Instead use `success` or `complete` depending on your particular use case.